# ADT bundle not installed in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, java, android, wine, eclipse

I downloaded ADT bundle from android developer site.

Bundle name is :-  `adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-2014031.zip`

It contains eclipse, and sdk folder.

In eclipse folder, there is one eclipse executable file. I try to open this using wine1.7,
`Wine Windows Program Loader`

but it shows

`The Z:\home\devsda\Downloads\adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321\eclipse\eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its home directory`

Please help me to install ADT bundle in Ubuntu 12.04, ,so that I will start my project.

Comment: You don't need wine to run the ADT.

Comment: @hbdgaf Then please tell me the steps.

Comment: Which step are you getting stuck on? http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Answer (score 4):

```
unzip adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-2014031.zip  
cd adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-2014031/eclipse
./eclipse
```